# How to use multiprocessing to parallelize a filtering function that collects items matching given conditions?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My program generates possible teams and then filters valid ones for fantasy basketball, it has the following constraints:

- 7 players per team
- budget less than or equal to 70 M
- at least 1 player per each position (PG, SG, SF, PF, C)

Here is a definition of a player and an example of a team:

```
from collections import Counter
from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import combinations

BUDGET = 70.0
MINIMUM_BUDGET_USED = BUDGET * 0.985
PLAYERS_PER_TEAM = 7

@dataclass
class Player:
    full_name: str
    club: str
    position: str
    price: float

team_example = (
 Player(full_name='Jarred Vanderbilt', club='MIN',position='PF', price=5.6),
 Player(full_name='Doug McDermott', club='SAS', position='SF', price=4.6),
 Player(full_name='Mohamed Bamba', club='ORL', position='C', price=9.3),
 Player(full_name='Caris Levert', club='IND', position='SG', price=9.0),
 Player(full_name="De'Aaron Fox", club='SAC', position='PG', price=11.8),
 Player(full_name='Giannis Antetokounmpo', club='MIL', position='PF', price=16.0),
 Player(full_name='Julius Randle', club='NYK', position='PF', price=13.6)
)
```

Having generated all the possible combinations of 7 players:

```
def generate_teams(players, players_per_team=PLAYERS_PER_TEAM):
    return combinations(players, players_per_team)
```

I want to keep only valid ones:

```
def keep_valid_teams(possible_teams):
    return [pt for pt in possible_teams if is_valid_team(pt)]

def is_valid_team(possible_team):
    return all([are_correct_positions(possible_team),
                is_valid_budget(possible_team),])

def are_correct_positions(possible_team):
    positions = Counter(p.position for p in possible_team)
    return len(positions) == 5 and max(positions.values()) <= 3

def is_valid_budget(possible_team):
    budget_used = sum(p.price for p in possible_team)
    return budget_used >= MINIMUM_BUDGET_USED and budget_used <= BUDGET
```

My question is how to use multiprocessing to parallelize `keep_valid_teams()` function.

Comment: you mean like with [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)?

Comment: yes, such as `map`, I don't know how to apply it in this context with predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. You need to turn your function into a map()

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def keep_valid_teams(possible_teams):
    with Pool(5) as p:
      is_valid_team_list = p.map(is_valid_team, possible_teams)
      return [pt for pt, is_valid_team in zip(possible_teams, is_valid_teams_list) if is_valid_team]
```

Comment: It does work. As far I understand, it operates in two phases: makes a bitmap of valid teams and then combines `True` ones?

Comment: Correct. Also note that the "5" parameter is the number of processes. You might also like to look at pypy

Comment: So one has to decompose it into two operations since it is impossible to do it in one sitting via `map`?

Comment: Generally speaking map has a one-to-one relationship of input records to output records. reduce is used when there are more input records than output records. It is possible to implement the built in functions sum(), filter() as reduce operations or map-reduce but not a map

Comment: That's why I was struggling to get the desired result via `map` only. Thank you!